# Is it possible to run a script on keyboard input language change?

Tags: keyboard, scripts, xmodmap

I'm interested in running a script whenever I manually change the input language.
This is because my xmodmap is forgotten whenever I change input languages, so a solution to that would also be useful.

I am not interested in solution that use a script to change the language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity, and use indicator-keyboard to change the keyboard input, then in 14.04 at least we can exploit the fact that this changes the GSettings key `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.current`. Here is a Python script that listens for changes to that key and then calls a function that prints some information and execs a subprocess.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from gi.repository import Gio, GObject

import subprocess

def on_changed(settings, key):
  print("Key changed", key, "to", settings.get_uint(key))
  subprocess.call(["touch", "/tmp/last-input-change"])

def main():
  settings = Gio.Settings("org.gnome.desktop.input-sources")
  settings.connect("changed::current", on_changed)
  loop = GObject.MainLoop()
  loop.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```